# Tangential quadrilateral and incircle chord

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

let side AD,BC of a tangential quadrilateral ABCD be tangent to its incircle at points M,N, respectively. Let line segments MN and AC intersect at point E. Given that AM= 3 , CN=6, AC=18.
Find the length of segment AE.

I am unable to use the fact that AM=3 and CN=6. I also tried using stewart theorem to get some relationship between AE and CE But it didnt work.

Comment: Hint: Find similar triangles.